# CSV module, Python: list index out of range

Tags: python, csv, import, module

So, I'm trying to use the CSV module in Python to get data from only some columns from two excel files. I'm new to programming, so might have made a very stupid mistake, please bear with me...

This is how it looks:

```
import sys
import csv

##functions

resultsdir = "/blah"

filename1=sys.argv[1]
filename2=sys.argv[2]
out = open(sys.argv[3],"w") 

#filename1,filename2 = "blub", "blub2"

reader1 = csv.reader(open(resultsdir+"/"+filename1+".csv"), delimiter= '\t')
reader2 = csv.reader(open(resultsdir+"/"+filename2+".csv"), delimiter= '\t')

fields1 = reader1.next()
fields2 = reader2.next()

CNVs1 = dict()
CNVs2 = dict()
```

Now I want to get the data from 3 columns from the two excel files, this is what I did:

```
for row in reader1:
    start = row[4] #start being the title of the 5th column, this is probably where I went wrong...
    end = row[5]
    BF = float(row[9])
    CNVs1[chr].append([int(start),int(end),BF])
```

and the same again for reader2.
When I run it I get the following error message:

```
start = row[4]
list index out of range
```

I don't know what that means in this case, and as I said, I'm new to this so it might be something really simple. Any ideas?

Comment: Your file has *at least* one row in it with fewer than 5 columns in it.

Comment: Could you suggest a way in which I could get the data only from column 5, 6 and 9 from the excel files?

Comment: You are doing it correctly, but you need to *make sure* you have rows with that many columns. Test `len(row)` first, perhaps?

Comment: I do have that many columns, I'm sorry but I'm quite confused about this. Does row[4] get the data from the 5th column? 

I think maybe I shouldn't use row, because what I want are all the rows from column 5,6 and 9. I don't know how to do that, though...

Answer (score 0):

Try using **Pandas**'s `read_csv` function and explicitly specify the columns that you are going to be using. For example,

```
import pandas as pd

# some code

reader1 = pd.read_csv('excelfile.csv', usecols=[4,5,6])
reader1 = reader1.values.tolist()

# Now you can access the elements in the list reader1

for row in reader1:
    print(row)
```

How you choose to modify this is completely your choice.
Also, if you want to specify a range of columns which are in series, then you can also use the `range` function in `usecols` like this:
`usecols=range(4,7)` where the columns starts at column 4 and end at column 6 (not considering column 7).
You can always find the documentation and examples for using **Pandas** online. It's a great library.
I'm not sure if you want another suggestion, but I would say use `defaultdict` instead of the inbuilt `dict()` function in your code.